# Converting string to an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string, object

Below is the code I am working on, my goal is to convert string to an actual object and just simply display the data from ajax call. But it seems that the string value cant work this way.

```
var string = "first: 'George', last: 'Smith'";

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'ajax.php',
   data: {string}
}).done(data){
   alert(data);
}
```

Comment: How you get this string?

Comment: the json string format is invalid.... can you share how it is created

Comment: How it is created what? This is my entire code, I am just trying to convert the string to an object

Comment: @user3135626 i mean how you get this string? it always have this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
data: Function('return {' + string + '};')()
```

Comment: Yep, this answer my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @user3135626 so also see about [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), like `JSON.parse('{'+string+'}')`

Comment: @user3135626 I agree with Grundy, but I've chosen the `Function()` way since the input is not a valid json string.

Comment: @wared yep, string with unknown format and code with function also will be work not for all path

Comment: @Grundy Well, it's hard to predict from the informations provided currently, I totally agree with you on that point :) Then, we could also discuss about the lack of security due to dynamic code evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try this:**

var Params= {first: 'George', last: 'Smith'};

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'ajax.php',
                data: JSON.stringify(Params),
                contentType: 'application/json',}).done(data){
   alert(data);
}
```

Comment: @user3135626..can you update your question clearly//

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is:

1. Do an AJAX call and receive data.
2. The received data will be a string, but with a special format, what many use is Json.
3. You'll create your object "manually".
4. Then, you'll populate your object's fields with the Json values.

There are plenty of examples on the web.